# The Chinese Mars rover and lander can be seen in the same picture. What device took the photo?

Tags: mars, china

The China Space News Agency published an image showing the Chinese Mars rover and lander in the same photograph.

What camera took the picture?

[image]

Source: [CNSA](http://www.cnsa.gov.cn/)

Comment: It looks like someone in China liked the movie Wall-E

Comment: It is all explained here: https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/aiOXxrnrcY8

Answer (score 11):

The group picture was taken by a wireless camera that had been released by the rover on the ground, from its bottom side. See this article in Chinese: http://www.cnsa.gov.cn/n6758823/n6758838/c6812123/content.html and use the Automatic Translator.

I believe the explanation in Chinese reads:

"The picture of the "touring group" was taken after the rover traveled about 10 meters south of the landing platform, released the separate camera installed at the bottom of the vehicle, and then retreated in the vicinity of the landing platform. The separate camera took pictures of the movement of the rover and the photo of the rover and the landing platform. The image was transmitted to the rover through wireless signals, and then relayed back to Earth by the rover through the orbiter."

Comment: Can the rover retrieve the camera, or did they really carry a camera to Mars to take lander selfies?

Comment: Surprising that you don't see tracks from the camera's location to the rover.  Did it drive around the long way just so as to avoid its tracks being visible in the shot?  Or did they wait for the wind to blow and obscure the tracks before taking the picture?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think FOV is small enough to hide closer tracks and terrain hides those far away. I think you can kinda see mark below left leg of a lander (big horizontal dark line) and one symmetrical relative to the rover

Comment: It may be an optical illusion, but if you look at the path that would be extended from its treads, you can see that there's no large rocks along it, and there may even be a slight depression.  Assuming it's actually there, the rover would have gone over the large rock in the middle, and stopped right before the big rock at the lower left.  If the ground is more rocky than dusty, it's quite plausible to not leave clear tracks.